# Theme not loading for main site or Admin - Just shows The menus in Text

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

Currently running magento 1.9.xx Not sure exactly which version, I have (And still and away on holiday) and I have been called as our magento store is not working.

I have scoured the logs, done everything I can think of to try and solve the issue which is when the site loads it just shows text none of the graphics etc. This is true for the admin side of the site too.

I'm really not sure what I should be looking for to solve this. Can anyone give me pointers please ?

I have cleared the cache files, deleted all the sessions, I just cant find anything wrong. I used `magento-check.php` shows its all the requirements are installed.
[image]

This is not a duplicate, I have checked that issue, and checked things like the db `core_config` etc, however has proved not able to resolve

Comment: Hi Marcel, not a duplicate, This issue affects both admin and main site. DB etc are correct and I am unable to find a reason !

Comment: `core_config_data` check for URL. Alternatively view source & check CSS  JS has correct path.

Comment: Hi Ankit - Both seem fine

Answer (score 1):

I have had this happen to me, a few things you can check:

- Make sure all theme files are in the correct place (ie: path)
- Disable all `css`, `html`, `js` minification modules
- Disable any recently installed module
- Turn off compilation
- Disable all cache
- Clear all cache

--
If you are using any type of reverse proxy, try connecting to the port of the web-server directly or disable the reverse proxy until you have resolved the issue.

Google pagespeed if enabled, should also be disabled.

If above fails, restore from a known good backup.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that your permissions are setup correctly? You won't typically see this issue unless minification is turned on for CSS or JS, but permissions can still prevent your resources from being read correctly.

[Reset Magento permissions](https://gist.github.com/zdravkok/7fe980b0a4da08dda281)

Comment: Hi Michael, Yes I belive so - So much I also tried with 777 permissions !

Comment: Sorry, that has to be frustrating. Are you able to pull up the developer console in your browser to see what errors you're receiving? It may be helpful to know if those stylesheets aren't being found at all (404) or if they're being blocked by the server (403).

Comment: I have double checked everything I do see this: frontend/default/ma_cance/css/styles.css3.php?url=/frontend/default/ma_cance/   Error 503 Service unavilable ?

Comment: The 503 error may point to the larger issue, but it doesn't quite explain why your admin looks equally messed up. Do the logs that you checked include the Apache server logs? Also, I know that it's not ideal on a production site, but is it possible to switch to the default Magento theme, just to see if the issue is isolated to the Ma Cance theme?

Comment: Other sites on the server are running really well, Im not sure how to return to the default theme ?